# Passing a string from main method to paint in the same class file

Tags: java, arrays, swing, graphics, methods

I have started learning java programming recently and I have started doing some graphics. I am in the process of making a GUI for the graphics and I am having some trouble with passing the shape that was selected from an array using JOptionPane.showInputDialog. 
Would it be advisable to create methods for each 2D shape I want to draw and then have the paint method in another class file and overload it?
Can I have some assistance please.
My code is shown below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test extends JFrame {

    String x1; // starting x co-ordinate
    String y1; // starting y co-ordinate
    String r1; // radius for circle
    String l1; // length for shape
    String h1; // height for shape
    String draw;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int r = 0;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test frame = new test();
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                        @Override
                        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                            return new Dimension(2000, 2000);
                        }
                    };
                    // frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(panel),
                    // BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setSize(1200, 600);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public test() {

        String[] shapes = { "Circle", "Ellipse", "Line", "Rectangle" };

        String drawShape = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Select a shape to be drawn: ", "Drawing 2D Shapes",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, shapes, shapes[0]);

        if (drawShape == "Circle") {
            System.out.println("Shape selected is: " + drawShape);

            x1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Input center (x value): ");
            y1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Input center (y value): ");
            r1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input radius: ");

            // parsing the variables from String to Integer
            x = Integer.parseInt(x1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(y1);
            r = Integer.parseInt(r1);
        }

        if (drawShape == "Ellipse") {
            System.out.println("Shape selected is: " + drawShape);

            x1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Input x starting point: ");
            y1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Input y starting point: ");
            l1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Width: ");
            h1 = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Height: ");

            // parsing the variables from String to Integer
            x = Integer.parseInt(x1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(y1);
            l = Integer.parseInt(l1);
            h = Integer.parseInt(h1);
        }

        if (drawShape == "Line") {
            System.out.println("Shape selected is: " + drawShape);

            x1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input point 1: ");
            y1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input point 2: ");
            l1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input point 3: ");
            h1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input point 4: ");

            // parsing the variables from String to Integer
            x = Integer.parseInt(x1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(y1);
            l = Integer.parseInt(l1);
            h = Integer.parseInt(h1);
        }

        if (drawShape == "Rectangle") {
            x1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Input x starting point: ");
            y1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Input y starting point: ");
            l1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Width: ");
            h1 = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Height: ");

            // parsing the variables from String to Integer
            x = Integer.parseInt(x1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(y1);
            l = Integer.parseInt(l1);
            h = Integer.parseInt(h1);
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        // drawing the shape
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, l, h);
        g2.draw(r);


        /*
         * Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, r, r);
         * g2.draw(circle); g2.drawString("This is a Circle", (x + (r / 2)), y);
         * 
         * g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255));
         * System.out.println("Shape selected is: " + type);
         * 
         * Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, l, h); //
         * defining // the // object // graphically g2.draw(ellipse);
         * g2.drawString("This is a ellipse", x, y);
         * 
         * g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255));
         * System.out.println("Shape selected is: " + type);
         * 
         * Line2D.Double line1 = new Line2D.Double(x, y, l, h); g2.draw(line1);
         * g2.drawString("Point 1", x, y); g2.drawString("Point 2", l, h);
         */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options.  Just like you have x,y etc as class variables, make your drawShape a class variable.  Then in your paint method, you would know what to draw.

At some point you might want to draw more than one shape.

I would create a class for each shape you want to draw.  They should all implement an interface that has one method "draw" which would take a Graphics as a parameter.

Lets say your interface is called MyShapeI.  Your class would have a collection of MyShapeI objects.

Then instead of setting class variables, you would create a new instance of say MyCircle, and set its x,y,r fields, and add it to your collection.

Lastly in paint, you would loop through your collection, and call each objects draw method.

This allows you infinite possibilities.  You could have a MyElephant class and it would know how to draw an elephant at the specified x,y point.